# Perl IDE Padre: how to format the source code

Tags: perl, padre

How can I have something like in eclipse, highlight the lines, right click Source --> Format, and make the code line up nicely.

Comment: Check Tools -> Preferences -> Indentation.

Comment: Finally I figured out. First download the plugin gzip from here:http://search.cpan.org/~azawawi/Padre-Plugin-PerlTidy-0.22/lib/Padre/Plugin/PerlTidy.pm, then installed from Tools --> Module Tools --> Install Local Distribution. Then from Tools --> Plugin Manager, enable the Perl Tidy. Finally I can see this menu: Tools/Perl Tidy/Tidy the Active Document, as mentioned here http://padre.perlide.org/features/perl-tidy.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out. First download the plugin gzip from here: search.cpan.org/~azawawi/Padre-Plugin-PerlTidy-0.22/lib/Padre/…, then install it from Tools --> Module Tools --> Install Local Distribution. Then from Tools --> Plugin Manager, enable the Perl Tidy. Finally I can see this menu: Tools/Perl Tidy/Tidy the Active Document, as mentioned here padre.perlide.org/features/perl-tidy.html.

Comment: However, the problem is the latest Padre IDE: dwimperl-5.14.2.1-v7-32bit.exe, doesn't work well in Windows 2012 64bit. The mouse wheel doesn't work, click files in Show Project Browser always being blank. Is there a 64bit of Padre IDE?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [Perl::Tidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod) which is [highly configurable](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) that does auto formatting of Perl code. Padre has a plugin to use it. You can [find the documentation here](http://padre.perlide.org/features/perl-tidy.html).

> Padre has a plugin called Padre::Plugin::PerlTidy that provides integration with the above module. It uses the default settings of perltidy or the settings of the current project to tidy the current file or the current selection in the editor.

It probably will use the `.perltidyrc` config file in your project directoy, though I am note sure about that.

Comment: After spending half an hour trying to figure out how to install a plugin, I found this:http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/INSTALL.html, and was again shocked by the complication of the installation. I was expecting like install a plugin to Jenkins, or any other modern tools. Guess need more time to figure out how to use it. But thanks a lot, have to have to drink before the installation.

Comment: @jir I don't know about the Padre plug-in, but perltidy is just a perl module. Install it from cpan.

Comment: I am using  Padre 0.94 & Perl Tidy is already installed but need to enable: `tools > Plug-in manager > select Perl Tidy > enable it `